# Почему не отрабатывает hover?

Tags: css, css3, hover

Есть такой стиль:

```
a {
background:black;
}
a:before {
background:red;
}
a:hover a:before {
background:white
}
```

Почему то стиль с наведением не меняет цвет на белый. Почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
a {
background:black;
}
a:before {
background:red;
}
a:hover,a:before {
background:white
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

вы пытаетесь дать цвет вложенной ссылке, всего лишь нужно поставить запятую в провило

```
    a:hover,
    a:before 
    {
        background:white
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать такую конструкцию `a:hover:before` для изменения контента в `:before` при наведении на ссылку.

```css
a {
  color:red;
  background:black;
}

a:before {
  content: ">>>";
  width: 50px;
  color: black;
  background:red;
}

a:hover, a:hover:before {
  background:white
}
```

```html
<a url='#'>link</a>
```